# Indy 10 server : How to send JSON response?

Tags: json, delphi, indy10

I am looking for a simple code example, using `Data.DBXJSON`'s `TJSONObject` to build a response and return it in `AResponseInfo.ContentText`.

Google does not seem to be my friend today :-(

Comment: The very first hit returned [`this example`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/JSON).

Comment: Lolx! I wonder what search sting you used. I managed to waste an hour and not find that. Please post as an answer for future searchers, as I I am sure there is none currently on this site.

Comment: I've searched "docwiki TJSONObject". About the answer, well, it would be a link only answer and I'm not sure if I could copy the content here. To build my own example I don't have enough time right now, so let's keep it opened for someone else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is in Embarcadero's documentation.  There is [an example](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/JSON) showing how to create and parse JSON strings.  `TJSONObject` has a `ToString()` method, eg:

```
var
  JSON: TJSONObject;
begin
  ...
  JSON := TJSONObject.Create;
  try
    // populate JSON as needed...
    AResponseInfo.ContentText := JSON.ToString;
  finally
    JSON.Free;
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Thanks a 1,00,000. Implemented d& working. T'would be nice, though to see some methods to add an array, a pair, etc, instead of just building a huge string. Nvm, it works.

Comment: If you're serializing objects, you might be interested in JSON object marshalling rather than building JSON manually. That saves a lot of work.

Comment: [The documentation example](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/JSON) shows you how to add a `pair` to a JSON object.